# How to Correctly Rewrite URI in Address Bar Using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am setting up wildcard subdomains on a new site, and I'm struggling with the htaccess settings.

I have the A record set up, and the htaccess is correctly redirecting the user to the correct subdomain. But the URI in the address bar isn't showing exactly as I want it to.

Here is the current htaccess code I am using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.domain\.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)/([^:]*):\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1 [QSA]
```

My desired result would be:

- User enters - subdomain.domain.co.uk/folder
- User sees content of - domain.co.uk/subdomin/folder
- Address bar shows - subdomain.domain.co.uk/folder

The current result is:

- User enters - subdomain.domain.co.uk/folder
- User sees content of - domain.co.uk/subdomin/folder
- Address bar shows - subdomain.domain.co.uk/subdomain/folder

Comment: Your rule looks ok and it should work . Do you have have any other rules or directive in htaccess that can redirect your subdomain to the maindomain url?

Comment: @starkeen no that is the entire htaccess file.